# How do I get the specified values into respective position

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a string of text, for example

```
"{"Date": 01/01/2019, "0": "John", "1": "Jack", "3": "Tom", "4": "Will", "5": "Joe"}"
```

Also, I have an entity

```
function demo(first, second) {
    this.first = first,
    this.second = second
}
```

Is it possible to transform the string of text into the entity? For example,

`"Date"` goes to `first`

`01/01/2019` goes to `second`

---

`"0"` goes to `first`

`"John"` goes to second

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @smart-googler A list with two columns having their respective values. For instance `first` column will have "Date", "John", "Jack".... then `second` column will have "01/01/2019", "0", "1"... etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own `class` and then create objects iterating on your json object

```js
class CustomObject {
   constructor(x, y) {
     this.first = x;
     
     this.second = y;
   }
}

// your initial data as a json into a string
const str = '{"Date": "01/01/2019", "0": "John", "1": "Jack", "3": "Tom", "4": "Will", "5": "Joe"}';

// transform your string into a json object
const json = JSON.parse(str);

// Build the custom objects, using the data inside of the json object
// The notation [x, y] is called -> destructuring
const objs = Object.entries(json).map(([x, y]) => new CustomObject(x, y));

// Now that we have the objects, display the values stored inside
// each one of them, to show they are correctly settled
objs.forEach(x => console.log(x.first, x.second));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Object.keys(json)` will do the trick in combination with the `map` function:

```js
const str = '{"Date": "01 / 01 / 2019", "0": "John", "1": "Jack", "3": "Tom", "4": "Will", "5": "Joe"}';
const json = JSON.parse(str);

function demo(first, second) {
    console.log(first, second);
    this.first = first,
    this.second = second
}

Object.keys(json).map(key => {
    demo(key, json[key]);
});
```